# Find all integers $a,b,c$ such that $0 \le a,b,c \le 1000$ and $1001|a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Find all integers $a,b,c$ such that $0 \le a,b,c \le 1000$ and $1001|a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc-1$
We have to check divisibility of $7,11,13$ and we may use the identity $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$
But I can't approach further.
Help!

Comment: Maybe $$(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$ helps

Comment: There are about 20000 to 40000 such triples, e.g. (216,852,562). I checked this with a small python program. What is the souce of this Problem?

Comment: it has 622080 solutions